# Google Maps partial / geo-bound styling

Tags: google-maps, maps, leaflet, openlayers-3

I'm trying to wrap my head around some advanced Google Maps styling.
Rather than applying the same style throughout the map, is it possible to apply different styles to parts of the map?

I've also been looking into overlaying two maps, but couldn't get much further with that approach. Polygons are not an option, because I want it to be a 'natural' map.

Would this otherwise be possible with Leaflet, OpenLayers or another framework?

Comment: Have a feeling over [these examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/examples/).

Comment: Found an example that looks promising, thanks! http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/examples/layer-swipe.html